# How can I add an infobox to a plotly plot in R?

Tags: r, plotly

I am using R plotly to display datapoints. Each datapoint has texts attached to it, which I would like to display in an infobox when the corresponding datapoint is clicked.

My code is showed below. Currently "MESSAGE_BODY" is being displayed in the tooltip, but it will not do the trick when the text is lenghty, because the texts exceeds the limits of the tooltip.

Below my original code I provide a reproducible an example of what I mean by "Exceeds the limits".

Original code:

```
plot_ly(PLS.scores, 
x = Comp1, 
y = Comp2,
type = "scatter",
mode = "markers",
color = as.factor(TARGET),
colors = c("red", "green"),
text = paste("Message:", MESSAGE_BODY))
```

Reproducible example:

```
install.packages("plotly")
library(plotly)

texts <- c("This is a short text and it works fine with the tool tip",
           "This text also work fine with the tooltip",
           "So does this one",
           "This text however, is so lengthy that it exceeds the limits if the tooltip. Therefore it would be extremely nice to be able to show such lengthy texts in a separate window with scrollbars! Or at least it is so lenghty that i hope you get the point... ")

dataX <- c(1,2,3,1)
dataY <- c(2,1,3,3)
TARGET <- c(1,0,1,0)

df <- data.frame(dataX,dataY,TARGET,texts)

plot_ly(df, 
x = dataX, 
y = dataY,
type = "scatter",
mode = "markers",
color = as.factor(TARGET),
colors = c("red", "green"),
text = paste("Message:", texts))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `<br>` to seperate text to the new line

```
texts <- c("This is a short text and it works fine with the tool tip",
       "This text also work fine with the tooltip",
       "So does this one",
       "This text however, is so lengthy that it exceeds the limits if the tooltip. <br> Therefore it would be extremely nice to be able to show such lengthy texts in a separate window with scrollbars!<br> Or at least it is so lenghty that i hope you get the point... ")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is however not the solution I am looking for, and your probably realize that :) However, do you have a suggestion to how to do add <br> programically? I have many texts and it does not make sense to do this manually.

Comment: This will do the trick "gsub('(.{1,3})(\\s|$)', '\\1\n', longstring)", I will however not accept your answer as a solution since I asked for a separate infobox.